# Javascript clone/append either affects the wrong image or all images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pretty basic function that gets a result set of images based on search input

```
function appendSomeItems(url, id, name, style) {
  return '<div><div class="md-card md-card-hover"><div class="gallery_grid_item md-card-content getImage"> <img class ="uk-align-center imageClick"></a><div class="gallery_grid_image_caption"> <span class="gallery_image_title uk-text-truncate">' + name + '</span> <span>' + style + '</span> </div></div></div></div>';
}
```

This works perfectly fine, and it is called in another function that basically gets up to 10 images from the result set and appends them in a div.

I have another function where I'm clicking one image and I want THAT specific image to clone and append to another div. The problem is, using class *imageClick* it clones and appends all images to the new div. If I change *imageClick* to an ID then it only clones/appends the first in the set.

How can I alter this to only clone and append the clicked image?

```
$(document).on('click', '.imageClick', function handleImage() {
  console.log('good');
  var img = $(".getImage").children("img").clone();
  $("#holdImage").append(img);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) on `$(this)` to target only the currently clicked image:

```
var img = $(this).closets(".getImage").children("img").clone();
```

Your current HTML suggest that you have only one image element which you are cloning. In this case finding children is meaningless. Simply cloning `$(this)` is enough:

```
var img = $(this).clone();
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work! My only question: Each click on a new image appends the image to the other. Is there a way for this to work so that if image a is already appended but I click image b then it would replace a with b?

Comment: @TomN., Do you want to prevent adding the image when clicking on the newly created image?

Comment: I want to add whichever image is clicked, but if one is already appended to #holdImage then I want to replace it with whichever was just clicked. In other words, I only ever want one image in #holdImage at a time

Comment: @TomN., you can clear the html with `$("#holdImage").html('');` just before appending....

Comment: @TomN., you are most welcome, btw, you can also remove only the specific element like `$("#holdImage .imageClick").remove();` before appending...:)

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest`:

```
var img = $(this).closest(".getImage").children("img").clone(true);
```

Comment: I believe this is in fact working now. It seems to keep appending on each click, is there not a default to have it replace the last one? So if I click image A and it appends, then click image B it removes A and appends B?